# javascript append onclick func is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, append

```js
function ABC(obj) {
  $("#ID").append('<div onclick="obj.func();">TEST</div>');
}

ABC({func: function() { alert("abc"); } })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ID"></div>
```

If you run this function, you will not be able to run obj.func

Why is it not called defined?

How can I solve it?

Comment: what is there inside `obj.func()` function?And what is `obj` there?

Comment: @AlivetoDie: `function() { alert("abc"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML attributes aren’t a good way to attach event listeners, because they run in a global-ish scope. `obj` is present in your function’s scope, and so it won’t be visible to the code in the `onclick` attribute. You should create the element and attach the listener separately:

```
function ABC(obj) {
    // Create a DIV element
    var div = $("<div>");

    // Add an event listener that calls the function
    div.on("click", function () {
        obj.func();
    });

    // Append the created element to #ID
    $("#ID").append(div);
}
```

The function expression does have access to its parent scope.

If `obj.func` doesn’t use `this` and doesn’t return a value, you can also use that function as the listener directly:

```
div.on("click", obj.func);
```

Comment: If you have a lot of items to be appended to, how should you handle them all the way?

Comment: @YongBinLim: What do you mean by "all the way"?

Comment: There are a **[whole lot of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** not to use HTML event attributes.

Comment: I use a translator.
So my sentence is not natural.
I have a lot of tags to " append " to do.
Would you like to add the tags in the above way?

Comment: @YongBinLim: You can use this for any number of tags, in a loop, if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: @YongBinLim You'd have better to use a class, delegate event and pass `obj` as data to event handler. That way, you'd just bind one event handler for all these elements. EDIT: it looks like you even don't need to pass any data because the `obj.func` is the event handler in your case...

Comment: This is a good answer and does work, but you really didn't address why the original code doesn't work.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Expanded on "scope"

Answer (score 0):

```
function ABC(obj) {

    $("#question-header").append('<div id="this-div">TEST</div>');
   $("body").off("click","#this-div").on("click","#this-div",function(){ obj.func(); });
}

ABC({func: function() { alert("abc"); } });
```

This is 100% working .. check this , you can even put events other than click ...

Comment: But, you don't actually explain the problem or your solution.

Answer (score -1):

The actual problem is that by the time the element gets clicked, the `ABC` function will have completed and its `obj` argument will be out of scope. Since your code hard-codes `obj` into the click event code, `obj` has no meaning at that point and you get your `obj is not defined` error.

Now, HTML event attributes don't take functions as their values, they take executable JavaScript instructions. So, you don't want the `onclick` to be set to a function, you want it set to a string of JavaScript to execute and that can be returned from your function that is passed in:

```js
function ABC(obj) {
  // By invoking the function stored in the passed in object, we can 
  // inject the appropriate JavaScript to run when the element gets clicked.
  $("#ID").append('<div onclick="' + obj.func() + '">TEST</div>');
}

ABC({ 
   func: function() { return "alert('abc');"; }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ID"></div>
```

Comment: Why a down vote for the correct explanation of the problem with a working solution?

Comment: Embedding JavaScript in strings isn’t a good idea. See e.g. `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Ryan That's besides the point. My answer doesn't recommend this approach. It correctly answers the question and shows what to do to make it work.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the idea was to call `obj.func()` on click anyway, and good practices are never beside* the point.

Comment: @Ryan Answering the question is always the #1 job. That's what my answer does.

Comment: Well, like I said, it doesn’t do that either – the intent was obviously to call `obj.func()`, not have it return a string of JS.

Comment: @Ryan That's your opinion. I think the intent was for it to work. The OP says *Why is it not called defined?* (I've answered that in full) and then the OP says *How can I solve it?* (I've shown and explained this as well). Your answer is good and it is the better approach, but you side-step the opportunity to show the OP how his code could work in the name of "I've got a better way." In cases like that, you should show the solution using the OPs method and then provide your better way as well. You don't do that.

Comment: There isn’t a solution using the OP’s method. You can’t expose a function’s scope to an HTML attribute. Globals, your answer, etc. are just sidestepping the problem in a different (less helpful) way.

Comment: @Ryan I think that your interpretation of what the OP wants is incorrect. I believe that my answer shows the OP how to get the job they want done, done using a slight modification of his original code. Your solution takes a completely different approach, which (as I've said) is a good approach, but doesn't address the original attempt.